# Compiling TensorFlow with Intel C Compiler

Tags: python, c, linux, tensorflow, intel

Just Tried to build TF with icc and it keeps failing. 
the following is the command used for building:

> CC=icc bazel build --verbose_failures --config=mkl --copt=-msse4.2 --copt="-DEIGEN_USE_VML" -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

The following was the error output:

```
INFO: From Compiling tensorflow/contrib/memory_stats/ops/memory_stats_ops.cc [for host]:
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/contrib/memory_stats/_objs/memory_stats_ops_op_lib/tensorflow/contrib/memory_stats/ops/memory_stats_ops.o'
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined'
Warning #2011: predefined meaning of "__DATE__" discarded

Warning #2011: predefined meaning of "__TIMESTAMP__" discarded

Warning #2011: predefined meaning of "__TIME__" discarded

tensorflow/contrib/memory_stats/ops/memory_stats_ops.cc(29): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"

tensorflow/contrib/memory_stats/ops/memory_stats_ops.cc(29): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"

ERROR: /home/bert/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/image/BUILD:20:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/contrib/image:python/ops/_image_ops.so' failed: icc failed: error executing command
  (cd /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/de2d5e30e11a47d70dad7109465f3a0a/execroot/org_tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/opt/intel/intelpython3/bin/python \
    PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/opt/intel/intelpython3/lib/python3.5/site-packages \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL=0 \
  /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64/icc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/bin/intel64 -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -msse4.2 -DEIGEN_USE_VML '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/image/_objs/python/ops/_image_ops.so/tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.pic.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/image/_objs/python/ops/_image_ops.so/tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.pic.o' -fPIC -DEIGEN_MPL2_ONLY -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles -iquote external/protobuf -iquote bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -iquote external/eigen_archive -iquote bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/eigen_archive -iquote external/local_config_sycl -iquote bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/local_config_sycl -isystem external/protobuf/src -isystem bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/protobuf/src -isystem external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -isystem third_party/eigen3/mkl_include -isystem bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/third_party/eigen3/mkl_include -isystem external/eigen_archive -isystem bazel-out/local-py3-opt/genfiles/external/eigen_archive -DEIGEN_AVOID_STL_ARRAY -Iexternal/gemmlowp -Wno-sign-compare -fno-exceptions '-DINTEL_MKL=1' -fopenmp -msse3 -pthread -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc -o bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/image/_objs/python/ops/_image_ops.so/tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.pic.o): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 2.
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/local-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/contrib/image/_objs/python/ops/_image_ops.so/tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.pic.o'
icc: command line warning #10120: overriding '-msse4.2' with '-msse3'
icc: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined'
Warning #2011: predefined meaning of "__DATE__" discarded

Warning #2011: predefined meaning of "__TIMESTAMP__" discarded

Warning #2011: predefined meaning of "__TIME__" discarded

In file included from tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(17):
./tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h(317): warning #858: type qualifier on return type is meaningless
    const int graph_def_version() const { return graph_def_version_; }
    ^

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(88): error: type name is not allowed
      typename TTypes<float, 2>::ConstTensor distance_mat =
      ^

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(88): error: expected a ";"
      typename TTypes<float, 2>::ConstTensor distance_mat =
                                             ^

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(98): error: identifier "distance_mat" is undefined
              DistancePair(index1, index2, distance_mat(index1, index2)));
                                           ^

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(134): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(134): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(134): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(134): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(134): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(134): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"

tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc(134): warning #2196: routine is both "inline" and "noinline"

compilation aborted for tensorflow/contrib/image/kernels/bipartite_match_op.cc (code 2)
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 93.648s, Critical Path: 18.66s
```

The issue seems to be with a contrib, is it possible to exclude certain contribs from the compilation?
The Python used is intel python 3.5
As bit of background, the system is Ubuntu 16 running on dual x5550, the aim was to get better performance since plain TF on a PC (i7-4700mq) works much faster.

Comment: Even if it manages to build, how do you intend to use a shared library built by ICC inside python built by GCC?

Comment: python and the libraries are built from ICC, its comes as bundle with Intel® Parallel Studio XE.

Comment: From the very first warning, it is evident that the makefile is not compatible with icc.  You'll have to edit the makefile to make all compiler options fit.

Comment: Thank for that! this is using bazel, so there is a configure file, maybe there is way to be explicit about eh compiler with CROSSTOOL

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Intel compiler. You have to replace

```
typename TTypes<float, 2>::ConstTensor distance_mat =
```

with

```
auto distance_mat =
```

More info can be found in this [thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/738492)